# Pickle is refusing to serialize content with celery reporting ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle

Tags: python, json, ssl, celery, pickle

I am trying to put some python object mostly json serializable except datetime.datetime in rabbitmq queue and so using pickle to serialize.

celery_config file:

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
```

It is throwing an exception saying:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 174, in loads
    raise self._for_untrusted_content(content_type, 'untrusted')
ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)
```

[This link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html#serializers)
suggests I do message signing about which I have no clue.

Can someone please guide me through how do I work it out?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628016/how-to-disallow-pickle-serialization-in-celery ?

Comment: Hey Andy, I have checked with the above solution which isn't making any difference. Unfortunately I'am unable to comment and ask my doubts on it as I'am new to stack. Btw top answer suggests to put serializer as json which will not work in my case.

Comment: great! (or not great depending on how you look at things), top tip for asking questions here: say the things you've tried and what happened (e.g. this didn't work)! +1 for trying it!

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andy.Will do next time.I have even tried couple of things like creating private keys and generating ssl certs which didn't work either.I badly got stuck on this.

Answer (score 42):

Have you tried, this:

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle']
```

As indicated in this link ( http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-accept_content)
this setting accepts a list of serializer names and content-types, so you could either white-list the serializer or the content-types you expect to serialize.

So either do the above, or use SSL message signing… which is basically, building a ssh-key pair, and enabling `celery` to use your keys to get a secure connection.

You can activate message signing, by registering your "KEY" and "CERTIFICATE" with:

```
CELERY_SECURITY_KEY = '/etc/ssl/private/worker.key'
CELERY_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE = '/etc/ssl/certs/worker.pem'
CELERY_SECURITY_CERT_STORE = '/etc/ssl/certs/*.pem'
from celery.security import setup_security
setup_security()
```

As far as what that stuff means… and how it works, see:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x64.html

Also, for how to generate keys (and enable secure passwordless logins), see:
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
or http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh for more general links referenced therein.

Comment: Link for CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT updated to this: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-accept_content

Comment: The problem with this answer is that enabling SSL message signing does not enable complex objects to be delivered as task arguments, as of Celery 4.3.0. The `auth` serializer uses `json` underneath and not `pickle`. Forcing it to use `pickle` as transport would fail upon de-serialization as the worker can't properly decode it.