# kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: [<Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object> ... is not JSON serializable - only on localhost

Tags: python, django, celery, kombu

I am using Django + Celery + Kombu + rabbitmq: my task is successfully completed on server (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
[2016-01-21 02:29:05,027: INFO/MainProcess] Task vk_wall.tasks.get_wallposts_by_owner_id[cbdfbdf7-1f01-4cf1-bd5a-77fae7a07003] succeeded in 7.826467196922749s: [<Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost...
```

but on localhost (Windows 7) with the same settings raises an error:

```
[2016-01-21 02:34:54,296: ERROR/MainProcess] Task vk_wall.tasks.get_wallposts_by_owner_id[5ecbf611-15d7-4b75-ac8e-2575b5dc869a] raised unexpected: EncodeError(TypeError(TypeError("[<Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...'] is not JSON serializable",),),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 283, in trace_task
    uuid, retval, SUCCESS, request=task_request,
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\amqp.py", line 136, in store_result
    delivery_mode=self.delivery_mode,
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 165, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 241, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 59, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\kombu\five.py", line 131, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 55, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 164, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\anyjson\__init__.py", line 141, in dumps
    return implementation.dumps(value)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\anyjson\__init__.py", line 89, in dumps
    raise TypeError(TypeError(*exc.args)).with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\anyjson\__init__.py", line 87, in dumps
    return self._encode(data)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 370, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 269, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 348, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 246, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: [<Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, <Vkwallpost: Vkwallpost object>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...'] is not JSON serializable
```

So task marked as not completed, but actually task do all things i need.
I reviewed answers on similar questions: my task returns dict i.e. {'success': success}. It seems, that it try to serialize Vkwallpost objects which is Django model instance, but why.

my settings.py:

```
#BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
BROKER_URL = 'django://'

#: Only add pickle to this list if your broker is secured
#: from unwanted access (see userguide/security.html)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'pickle']
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='amqp'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
# postgresql
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+postgresql://postgres:111222@localhost/graphgrail'
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.cache:CacheBackend',
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json' #json pickle msgpack
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IMPORTS=["vk_wall.tasks"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects are not JSON serializable. If the serialisation succeeds on Linux this indicates that you are probably using the `pickle` serialisation method there.

I would suggest using the `pickle` serialization method in Windows by specifying it explicitly using one of the methods mentioned [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#serializers).

Comment: The problem is that if i replace all json to pickle in settings it refuse to process task because of security

Comment: sorry -that's not making much sense. what do you mean "because of security"? can you post the error message, if any?

Comment: the same ting as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578235/pickle-is-refusing-to-serialize-content-with-celery-reporting-contentdisallowed  The solution there provided did not help me

Comment: hang on - are you trying to return python objects in your results? this seems like a bad idea - have you tried re-structuring your code so that you do not pass objects - this will allow you to use only json

Comment: no, in return of my task no python or django objects, simple dict. I save django model in this task. So its impossible to rewrite code, i i think right solution is not to hand-made hacking django object to json

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "not to hand-made hacking django object to json". somewhere your code is trying to pass python objects as  celery results - that is what the traceback in your exception shows. you should probably not do this.